# How to change path in the commands of Makefile

Tags: makefile

## Question

If there is a command that has to run at a given path, how can I change the path in makefile?

## Sample Description

**For example**, the structure of my project folder(`D:\proj`) is shown below

```
--proj
----Makefile
----src
------test.py
```

The content of `test.py` is below

```py
import sys
cur_path = sys.path[0]
print("Current path:%s" %cur_path)
```

The content of `Makefile` is below

```
chdir:
   cd .\src
   python test.py
```

The command `make chdir` cannot run and it throws error "cannot find file". Obviously, `cd` command not work.

How can I realize `cd` command in Makefile?

- Assume that we cannot change the command `python test.py` to `python .\src\test.py`

## My expectation

The command `make chdir` runs normally without changing the command `python test.py`

Answer (score 0):

Change the content of Makefile into

```
chdir:
   cd ./src &&\
   python test.py
```

**Each line of command has no context relation, unless you use `&&` to connect them**.

Comment: This won't work if your makefile is invoking `cmd.exe` as it's shell (you're on Windows apparently) rather than a POSIX `sh` shell.